add decoration to codeMirror editor word
i have custom plugin for codeMirror that will detect misspeled words:
const spellCheckPlugin = ViewPlugin.fromClass(
  class {
    constructor(view: EditorView) {
      this.checkSpelling(view.state);
    }

    update(update: ViewUpdate) {
      if (update.docChanged) {
        this.checkSpelling(update.state);
      }
    }

    checkSpelling(state: EditorState) {
      const text = state.doc.toString();

      const words = text.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "").split(/\s+/);

      words.forEach((word) => {
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

        if (randomNumber === 1) {
          const span = document.createElement("span");
          span.className = "misspelled";
          span.textContent = word;
        }

        console.log("word:", word);
      });
    }
  }
);

i'm using with my custom use:

const useCodeMirror = <T extends Element>(
  props: Props
): [MutableRefObject<T | null>, EditorView?] => {
  const refContainer = useRef<T>(null);
  const [editorView, setEditorView] = useState<EditorView>();
  //const { onChange, onScroll, reference, onScroll2, reference2 } = props;
  const { onChange, onScroll, reference, reference2, reference3 } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!refContainer.current) return;

    const startState = EditorState.create({
      doc: props.initialDoc,
      extensions: [
        vim(),
        keymap.of([...defaultKeymap, ...historyKeymap]),
        lineNumbers(),
        highlightActiveLineGutter(),
        history(),
        indentOnInput(),
        bracketMatching(),
        highlightActiveLine(),
        drawSelection(),
        markdown({
          base: markdownLanguage,
          codeLanguages: languages,
          addKeymap: true,
        }),
        oneDark,
        transparentTheme,

        syntaxHighlighting(syntaxHighlightingCustom),
        EditorView.lineWrapping,
        EditorView.updateListener.of((update) => {
          if (update.changes) {
            onChange && onChange(update.state);
          }
        }),
        spellCheckPlugin,
      ],
    });

    Vim.map(":", "<Esc>");

    const view = new EditorView({
      state: startState,
      parent: refContainer.current,
    });

    const scroller = view.dom.querySelector(".cm-scroller");
    if (reference && scroller) {
      reference.current = scroller as HTMLDivElement;
      scroller.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      // scroller.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll2);
    }

    const container = view.dom.querySelector(".cm-content");
    if (reference2 && container && reference3) {
      reference2.current = container as HTMLDivElement;
      reference3.current = container as HTMLDivElement;
    }

    setEditorView(view);

    return () => {
      view.destroy();
    };
  }, [refContainer]);

  return [refContainer, editorView];
};

export default useCodeMirror;

what i want is to replace misspeled word with word or something like that
so i can add styles and make it visible for users.
i'm not sure how to implement it, i checked codemirror.net page, but didnt find anything that i can use, or what i found is not supported
